# compiling references using bibdesk on TeXShop with achemso package for acs Format

Tags: citing, compiling, achemso, bibdesk

I'm new to LaTeX and the program TeXShop for mac.
I'm currently trying to write a lab report and trying to get a grasp on how to compile references on TeXShop using a .bib file. (if that makes sense)

I'm having several issues that I've tried searching answers for, but for some reason, there aren't a lot of ACS sources or explanations.

First, I'm using the achemso package to get the citations in the correct format with **\bibliographystyle{achemso}** followed by **\bibliography{name of file.bib}**. I've tried doing the several steps with compiling followed by the drop down macros menu Bibdesk and compiling several more times. my references do not appear with the console giving me several errors that I do not understand.

I'm hoping someone can help me understand what exactly I'm doing wrong.

`

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry} 
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} 
\usepackage{achemso}
\begin{document}
blah blah blah.\cite{1}
\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\bibliography{Dehydration of 2-Methyl-2-Butanol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't help with texshop as I use a different editor but assuming you have some `\cite` in your document, the process is latex (to extract the list of cite) then bibtex (to generate a bibliography for the cited works using information in the bib file), then latex again (to typeset the document including the generated bibliography).

Comment: when I try to generate the bibliography the console gives me errors such as

**This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017)
The top-level auxiliary file: Untitled.aux
The style file: achemso.bst
White space in argument---line 25 of file Untitled.aux
 : \bibdata{Dehydration
 :                      of 2-Methyl-2-Butanol}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file Untitled.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "1"
achemso 2017/05/18 v3.10i
(There were 2 error messages)**

Comment: don't put spaces in your `\cite` command (and is your main TeX document really called `Untitled.tex` ?

Comment: it is hard to help as you have shown no code but `\cite` should just take an arbitrary identifier like `\cite{abc}` with a matching `@misc{abc, .....}` in the bib file.

Comment: It is for now... i had to remake the whole document. How would I show you the code? Just copy and past?

Comment: `\bibliography` argument should be the name of a file: `\bibliography{foo}` tells bibtex to use `foo.bib`  and `\cite` should not take a number like `1` it should take the internal label as used in the bib file for the entry that you want to cite

Comment: Dehydration of 2-Methyl-2-Butanol is the name of the bib file
and that's the citation key I've set for my citation in bibdesk `\cite{1}`

Comment: it is? that's weird:-) It is simplest if you don't have spaces in filenames.  what is the key of the bib entry in that file that you want to cite? it is presumably not `1` ?

Comment: Ok, so I think I partially figured it out, because not I'm actually getting citations and the reference list appearing. although the formatting is all wrong for the reference itself.